# Overload binary struct operator

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, overloading

I've long sought for a solution to my dilemma both inside and outside the forum but I've found nothing. Thus I'll propose my problem to you, hoping for an advice.

I am building a structure that have to represent an image (bitmap) using a byte array. I've found nothing both fast and useful to fulfill my needs.

```
public struct image
    {
    BitmapData bmd;
    byte[] x;
    unsafe byte*[] xy;
    }
```

where the xy array should be only an array of pointer to allow the xy[4][5] trick to access the 5th byte of the 4th line.

In addition to a couple of constructors

```
image(ref Bitmap tbm)
{
    bmd = tbm.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, tbm.Width, tbm.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, tbm.PixelFormat);
    x = new byte[bmd.Stride * bmd.Height];
    Marshal.Copy(bmd.Scan0, x, 0, bmd.Stride * bmd.Height);
    unsafe
    {
        xy = new byte*[bmd.Height];
        xy[0] = (byte*)bmd.Scan0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bmd.Height; i++) { xy[i] = xy[0] + i * bmd.Stride; }
    }
}

image(ref image tx)
    {
    bmd = tx.bmd;
    x = new byte[tx.size()];
    tx.x.CopyTo(x,0);
    unsafe { xy = new byte*[tx.bmd.Height];  tx.xy.CopyTo(xy, 0); }
    }
```

I'd like to add an user friendly operator to
**copy by reference one image to the other**.
NOT similar to the second constructor that makes a new copy of the two arrays but only a thing like this

```
void linkTo(ref image source)
    {
    this.bmd = source.bmd;
    this.x = source.x;
    unsafe { this.xy = source.xy; }
    }
```

or better like this

```
static void link(ref image i1,ref image i2)
    {
    i1.bmd = i2.bmd;
    i1.x = i2.x;
    unsafe { i1.xy = i2.xy; }
    }
```

Since it's not possible to override (or overload?) the = operator neither to create a new operator <=8 I've tried to overload the shift operator this way:

```
public static void operator <<(ref image i1,ref image i2)
    {
    i1.bmd = i2.bmd;
    i1.x = i2.x;
    unsafe { i1.xy = i2.xy; }
    }
```

that ***piteously fails*** due to void return type and probably cuz I'm missing some points about overloading.

What i want to do is using the operator

```
myImage1 << myImage2;
```

to create a reference copy of myImage2 to myImage1 to allow the editing of myImage2 using myImage1 (for instance).

Something similar to

```
myImage1.linkTo(ref myImage2)
```

or

```
image.link(ref myImage1,ref myImage2)
```

of the previous example.

My question is: 
**how can i create or overload an operator to do what i've described above?** 
Are there any clear mistakes in my code?

Thank you for the attention!

Comment: `public static void operator <<(image i1, image i2)`: `i1` is value-copied because it's a struct. Any changes applied to it are discarded. Options to solve this are using a class (preferred) or calling the methods by ref. Also I wouldn't expect a shift operator to modify contents, so I would avoid that behavior.

Comment: For me the whole idea of creating a link to another image doesnt make sense, cause C# already works with references so if you pass Image A to a variable Image B and then modify it, it would already be applied to A. Given that Image is a class. So there is still your wish for easy addressing, you could implement a new class, that holds your image date in a one dimensional array and give this class an index operator [row, col] that just calculates the index with row*image.width + col. No nasty pointer magic involved

Comment: It seems very non-idiomatic to use a struct for your data type. Are you sure you want a struct and not a class? Do you really need value semantics for the type?

Comment: i used a struct because it has only to contain data and I've red that it's faster than a class.
I have to acquire tons of frames from different webcams and to manipulate them...I guess that creating 150 structure-type objects per second is faster than doing the same with class-type, isn't it?

Comment: Creating a Struct may be faster, but do you realy need this 0.0001ms or whatever is the difference? Copying a struct on the other hand needs more time than passing a reference of a class. So i would in your case go with the class, as long as you can achieve your 150 objects per second. Don't worry for perfomance problems you will possibly never have.

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. The key feature of a value type (i.e. `struct`) is that you can assign one instance to another and _it does exactly what you seem to be asking for here_. That is, a simple assignment of one `struct` value to another does in fact just copy the internal member values directly from one to the other. I agree with the other comments, suggesting that you're probably headed down the wrong path anyway. But as far as copying `struct`s goes, C# does exactly what you want, by default.

Comment: @PeterDuniho you are saying me that if i do
image i1=i2;
it'll copy the whole set of data (including the arrays)? My doubt was about the array that are not created when i declare image i1, (they are only declared)

Comment: No, I'm saying that if you assign the value of `i2` to the variable `i1`, it will copy the values of the _fields_ from each. That's all your `link()` method does. Are you under the mistaken impression that your `link()` method was doing something more than just copying the value of the fields themselves?

Comment: uhm...yes!!     x is an array of byte .   doing i1.x = i2.x; i'm only moving the "pointer" of the array and not creatin a new array in the heap! the other constructor that accept an image creates a new array and use the method copyTo to fill it! isn't it?